# Probability of defective cogs in a carton

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A company that manufactures cogs sells them in cartons of 100. It is historically known that about 1% of the cogs manufactured by the company are defective.

How do I find an expression for the probability that a carton has more than 2 defective cogs in it?

I'm not sure if this is a binomial distribution or hypergeometric, or neither, which is really confusing me.

Also, I know how to approximate this to the Poisson distribution, but that's not what I'm trying to do for this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note:There is a rule of thumb stating that the Poisson distribution is a good approximation of the binomial distribution if n is at least 20 and p is smaller than or equal to 0.05, and an excellent approximation if n ≥ 100 and np ≤ 10.

Here n = 100 and p = .01 and np = 1

Thus $$P(X =  x) = \frac{e^{-np}(np)^{x}}{x!}$$

Thus $$P(X> 2) = 1-P(X=0)-P(X=1)-P(X=2) = 1- \frac{e^{-1}(1)^{0}}{0!} - \frac{e^{-1}(1)^{1}}{1!}-\frac{e^{-1}(1)^{2}}{2!}$$

The required probability $= 1-0.367879441 -0.367879441-0.183939721
 = 0.080301397$

It is a binomial distribution with n = 100, k = 0,1,2 and p = .01 and q = .99.  Now

let us calculate using the binomial distribution

$$P(X>2) =1-{100\choose 0}*0.01^0*.99^{100} - {100\choose 1}*0.01^1*.99^{99} - {100\choose 2}*0.01^2*.99^{98}$$ 
$$ = 1-0.366032341273 - 0.36972963765 - 0.184864818825 = 0.079373202$$

[image]

[image]

Comment: Actually this is the answer to a follow up question asking me to approximate my expression to the Poisson distribution, which I can do. So that isn't what the original question is asking me for...

Comment: @Jaybee93, See the edit.  It is a binomial distribution with these parameters and could you see how cumbersome the calcuation is I did it using EXCEL and see the closeness of the solution

Comment: Thank you, that's very clear. Could you also approximate something like this to the normal distribution?

Comment: Yes you could and see the further edit.  Approximation is really bad.

Comment: With Continuity Correction, it works reasonably well.  Even then, the approximation is bad.  See Edit 2

Comment: But then it makes sense I guess, because normal approx only works when n and p are large. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

HINT: It's Poisson Distribution.

Find $P=P(no~defective) + P(1~defective) + P(2~defective)$

Ans = $1-P$

Comment: But I know that I can approximate the solution to Poisson, and I can do that, because it's what a follow up question to this is asking me to do. The original question is asking for an exact expression, not an approximation.

Comment: @Non material error, it is asking for more than 2. I have taken the liberty to change.  Forgive me if it bothered you.

Comment: @Jaybee93 Then, it wants you use binomial (n=100, p=.01). Apply binomial to the two cases for no, 1 and 2 defective, and substract from 1. The purpose of the question (overall including the followup) is to show the connections between binomial and poisson distribution.

Comment: @satishramanathan Thanks for the edit.